# How to do a SQL NOT NULL with a DateTime?

Tags: sql-server

How does one handle a `DateTime` with a `NOT NULL`?

I want to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM someTable WHERE thisDateTime IS NOT NULL
```

But how?

Comment: why doesn't it work? is the column set to accept null values?

Comment: can you give us your actual schema for the table in question, and the exact query you're using (if you simplified the query for the purposes of the question)? What you're doing ought to work just fine!

Comment: "obviously doesn't work" Why do you say that? It worked for me last time that I tried it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

erm it does work? I've just tested it?

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[DateTest]    Script Date: 09/26/2008 10:44:21 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DateTest](
    [Date1] [datetime] NULL,
    [Date2] [datetime] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
Insert into DateTest (Date1,Date2) VALUES (NULL,'1-Jan-2008')
Insert into DateTest (Date1,Date2) VALUES ('1-Jan-2008','1-Jan-2008')
Go
SELECT * FROM DateTest WHERE Date1 is not NULL
GO
SELECT * FROM DateTest WHERE Date2 is not NULL
```

Comment: I concur, I tested it as well.

Answer (score 2):

Just to rule out a possibility - it doesn't appear to have anything to do with the `ANSI_NULLS` option, because that controls comparing to NULL with the `=` and `<>` operators. `IS [NOT] NULL` works whether `ANSI_NULLS` is `ON` or `OFF`.

I've also tried this against SQL Server 2005 with `isql`, because `ANSI_NULLS` defaults to `OFF` when using DB-Library.

Answer (score 2):

I faced this problem where the following query doesn't work as expected:

```
select 1 where getdate()<>null
```

we expect it to show 1 because getdate() doesn't return null.
I guess it has something to do with SQL failing to cast null as datetime and skipping the row!
of course we know we should use IS or IS NOT keywords to compare a variable with null but when comparing two parameters it gets hard to handle the null situation.
as a solution you can create your own compare function like the following:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnCompareDates]
(
    @DateTime1 datetime,
    @DateTime2 datetime
)
RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN
    if (@DateTime1 is null and @DateTime2 is null) return 1;
    if (@DateTime1 = @DateTime2) return 1;
    return 0
END
```

and re writing the query like:

```
select 1 where dbo.fnCompareDates(getdate(),null)=0
```

Answer (score -2):

SELECT * FROM Table where codtable not in (Select codtable from Table where fecha is null)