# MySQL Query to display records based on time

Tags: mysql

Hi I have created an event table with the following fields:

- title
- start-date
- end-date
- venue

and I want to have a query that bring up events that have start and have not finished and another query to display events that have not started yet.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more? What have you tried so far?

Comment: What data type (date, datetime, timestamp, int...) is used for `start-date` and `end-date`?

Comment: I am not sure what data type they are as I created the fields in drupal ( I am new to mysql)

Comment: How we know when it is started or not?

Comment: execute `desc events;` in mysql client and post results here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want to achieve and assuming that `startdate` and `enddate` are of type `DATETIME` you can do

```
-- started but not finished
SELECT *
  FROM events
 WHERE startdate <= NOW()
   AND enddate > NOW();
```

Sample output (current date/time is `March, 06 2014 16:28:26+0000`):

```
| ID |  TITLE |                    STARTDATE |                      ENDDATE |  VENUE |
|----|--------|------------------------------|------------------------------|--------|
|  2 | Event2 | March, 04 2014 16:22:55+0000 | March, 08 2014 16:22:55+0000 | Venue2 |
```

```
-- not started yet
SELECT *
  FROM events
 WHERE startdate > NOW();
```

Sample output (current date/time is `March, 06 2014 16:28:26+0000`):

```
| ID |  TITLE |                    STARTDATE |                      ENDDATE |  VENUE |
|----|--------|------------------------------|------------------------------|--------|
|  3 | Event3 | March, 08 2014 16:22:55+0000 | March, 11 2014 16:22:55+0000 | Venue3 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/878699/2)** demo

Answer (score 0):

assuming that the data fields are empty strings until they've been set:

```
select * from events where start-date!='' and end-date='';
select * from events where start-date='';
```

also 
[How to do a SQL NOT NULL with a DateTime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138493/how-to-do-a-sql-not-null-with-a-datetime)